# Countering gravitational bead instability

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, gravity, geology, megastructures

I started thinking about Alderson disks. They are usually portrayed with large uninhabitable sections on either side of the habitable zone.

Why not just build the habitable zone, and save materials? (As if that were really a concern for Alien Space Bats building a freaking Alderson Disk....)

Well, the thinner the annulus is, the less well any local area approximates an infinite plane, and thus the less stable it is against radial collapse. *But*, [toroidal planets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toroidal_planet) are physically possible, so we could just have a toroid encircling a star with inner-facing surfaces being habitable... *but again*, toroidal worlds are subject to gravitational bead instability when the aspect ratio exceeds 3, and a torus just thick enough to produce Earth-like gravity and wide enough to encircle a star will have an aspect ratio *way, **way*** larger than 3! (For all practical purposes, it locally approximates an infinite cylinder.)

"How exactly would one counter bead instability in such a structure?" is probably too big of a question; I expect it will require [Clarketech](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ClarkesThirdLaw). But perhaps we can address something more tractable:

**What is the magnitude of geologic forces that would need to be actively countered to control bead instability in an "Alderson Torus"?**

Just how much suspension of disbelief would I be asking people to accept here?

Comment: Surely a toroidal planet encircling a star is subject to Ringworld instability, and will eventually collide with the star?

Comment: @JohnDallman That, too, but that's a separate issue for which countermeasures are much more obvious.

Comment: Is there any need for it to be toroidal? if it is rotating then centrifugal acceleration is creating the artificial gravity for the inner surface just like a ringworld and the mass of the thickness will create gravity for the outer surface as the centre of mass is the centre of the ring. I may have misunderstood your description but unless the outer face of the torus needs gravity, it may as well be a ringworld.

Comment: @JarredJones Yes; if the cross-section isn't circular, then its even *more* unstable. And yes, you *could* just build a ringworld instead, but that's a completely different sort of megastructure and doesn't actually address the question. Ringworlds have *their own ridiculous engineering issues, like requiring nuclear-strength materials or absolutely perfect magnetic bearings that can support continent-mass loads, and consuming energy to spin them up far beyond orbital velocity.

Comment: A circular cross-section does sound more stable but you wont need a thick mass if the torus is rotating and the inner surface is the habitable area and if it is not rotating only the outer surface will have gravity.

Comment: @JarredJones That's not how gravity works, even on a small torus. And this is not a small torus. Locally, it is a close approximation to an infinite cylinder, which has gravity perpendicular to the surface all the way around. The torus is rotating, but only at orbital velocity--spin it like a Ringworld, and it will explode.

Comment: Your right, I got that wrong. Interesting question, hope you get some solutions.

Comment: When I search ["bead instability"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22bead+instability%22&client=ubuntu&hs=9Ow&channel=fs&ei=HjZQY8HtLIeYgQaZhLboCA&ved=0ahUKEwjB9Lnu6uz6AhUHTMAKHRmCDY0Q4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=%22bead+instability%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyCAgAEKIEELADMggIABCiBBCwAzIICAAQogQQsANKBAhBGAFKBAhGGABQxQhYzhBgqRVoAXAAeACAAQCIAQCSAQCYAQCgAQHIAQPAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz) the first answer is this very question. What are these beads and why are they unstable?

Comment: @Daron A gravitationally-bound infinite cylinder (or sufficiently large torus) is in an unstable equilibrium--as long as the linear mass distribution is perfectly uniform, forces are zero; but if there is any local increase in density, it becomes self-reinforcing, gathering mass into a bead, and if there is any local decrease in density, it repels mass, forming partial beads on either side. Both positive and negative density anomalies cause each other, leading to the breakup of the cylinder into disconnected beads.

Comment: @Daron, think of a stream of water falling from a great height. As the water accelerates, it gets thinner because you have to stretch the same volume across a higher gallons per minute. Eventually, surface tension breaks the stream down into beads. Gravity works the same way. At planetary scales, solid rock is basically a fluid, so you'd wind up with an asteroid belt in no time.

Answer (score 1):

> Just how much suspension of disbelief would I be asking people to accept here?

**A lot**, but you can probably go away with it, as audience is unlikely to consider the different points of the settings separately, but more as a whole.

1. The quasistable toroidal planet hypothesis makes the assumption that the structure behaves *fluidly*, which can be accepted for typical rocky planets, but
   less so for a rigid structure. Shifting from planet-size to a solar system size adds some order of magnitude to the mechanical constraints of said structure.
2. Such toroid structure is metastable. Bead instability are the issue here, but if the structure is already rigid, you can just get away with it.
3. A rotating toroid structure will create local tidal force pulling matter from the inner part toward the external one. Using a ring-shape solves the issue, but as your rigid structure is there, you can as well stick with it.

To sum-up: the structure will face forces orders of magnitude above anything mankind can deal with today. The weakest item above involves energies comparable *at least* to continental drifts, requiring a fair share amount of suspension of disbelief to go through. An audience accepting any of the premises is unlikely to refuse the other ones just because it implies the structure being a few orders of magnitudes better.

Answer (score -2):

"Life could exist on either side of the disk, but the direction of gravity (the direction of "down") at any given place on the disk would be toward the center of mass of the overall system."

Any practical hypotheses based on this theory, would end up wanting.

Just how much suspension of disbelief would I be asking people to accept here?
Too much. If presented as a ground truth, the rest of the framework must be presented as fact.

Suspension of disbelief, only carries for plausible solutions within the perceived world.

Anything maybe possible in a magical, fantasy, or sci-fi worlds, but unless otherwise reasonably defined, The reader is bound to their interpretation.

Alderson disks in their nature defy logic. The missing logic must be provided.

Alderson disks were portrayed successfully in the movie "Upside Down" in 2012.